# How can I scroll down 50px after clicking a button?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, scroll

how can I scroll down my page in Angular after a button click?
I tried this, but it didn't work. So how can I let the page scroll 50px down?

```
window.scrollBy(0, 50);
```

Comment: Are you sure your viewport is overflowing? This code should work. However, if you have, for example, the `body` (or another full-page) element set to overflow, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: i don't know, what you mean with overflow, but I think the window.SOMECODE is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use angular [Viewportscroller](https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller#scrolltoposition) service. Which provide scrollToPosition method. you can define the postion as a arguments to this method.

**Try this:**

```
  constructor(private vps: ViewportScroller) {}

  scroll() {
    this.vps.scrollToPosition([0, 50]);
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9rs24h)